# Boot ubuntu from usb. Ubuntu is parallel with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

My PC has an SSD with Windows 10 installed, and I want to install Ubuntu into the second drive, an HDD. I have partitioned the drive, but I don't see the free space when booting. Here are two pictures to show the partitioning; first, from [Ubuntu Installation Partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0uTG.jpg), then from [Windows Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHhTd.png).

How can I successfully install Ubuntu into the 50 GB space on the second drive?

Comment: Personally I would unplug the SSD before proceeding. Not sure why your Disk Manager picture is different than your Something else picture?

Comment: Try converting your "Dynamic" partitions to basic.  The Ubuntu installer cannot handle the Microsoft proprietary "Dynamic" format.

Answer (score 1):

First, as *ubfan1* so nicely pointed out, you must convert the Microsoft *Dynamic* [partitioning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks) of your HDD ('Disk 1') to *Basic*; instructions are provided at https://superuser.com/questions/65939/converting-dynamic-to-basic-disk  .

Then, you can reboot the PC with your Ubuntu LiveUSB, and [following these instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0), install Ubuntu. When you get to the [Allocate Disk Space](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5) step, choose [Something Else](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) and specify you want to install into the 50GB partition on the HDD **sdb**.

**However** before you do anything, please back up what's in your Windows drives D: and E;, verify what's on the backup matches the files on the HDD; make another backup to a different drive (or cloud location), then verify what's on the second backup matches what's on the HDD.

Yes, it may be expensive and/or take time; but when you make changes to partitions on drives, sometimes data gets lost. Lost. Do you want to lose your data? You don't? Then back it up twice and verify each backup.